# Web Page Accessing only through specific computer systems

Tags: php

I want the web page to be accessed only on the specific system. It is like giving organizational access to the web page. The page can only be accessed through the computer systems within the organization. Any Idea how to implement it in PHP ?

Comment: How about `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lock web app only work for intranet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691329/lock-web-app-only-work-for-intranet)

Answer (score 0):

On PHP you can check for the IP address using $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] which will yield the IP address of the user. This might be sufficient in your case or not. It is sufficient if you know all the IP addresses in your organization and can create a white list to check against. If not, then you will need to set up a VPN and your users will need to log in to the VPN to be able to access the website. VPN will only allow access to users able to log in to the VPN and requests outside of that should not reach your PHP.